# Uncaught Error: Call to a member function query() on null in

Tags: php, pdo

I'm trying to connect and query my DB for testing. However, I'm getting this error and I don't know why.

Error message

> Uncaught Error: Call to a member function query() on null in

My class

```
class sales extends dbConnect
{
    public function getSales()
    {
        //$tpl = new TemplatePower($this->temp_dir.$tpl);
        //$tpl -> prepare();

        // Bing the latest sales
        $sql    =   "select * from journal";
        $stmt   =   $this->connect()->query($sql);
        while($stmt = $stmt->fetch()){
            echo $stmt['id'].'<br>';
        }}}
```

Connect to DB class

```
class dbConnect
{
    private $db_name    = "trust";
    private $db_user    = "root";
    private $db_pwd     = "1234";
    private $db_host    = "localhost";

    protected function connect()
    {
        $dsn = 'mysql:host='.$this->db_host.';dbname='.$this->db_name;
        $con = new PDO($dsn, $this->db_user, $this->db_pwd);
        $con -> setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE, PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't understand the purpose of dbConnect class. You don't do anything in there

Comment: Either add return or get rid of the class altogether

Comment: In the `dbConnect` class the `connect()` method doesn't return anything.

Comment: the dbConnect class connects to the data base and then I inherit this file to the other files so they connect to the database every time I need to query anything

Comment: you should never inherit from this class in the first place. please read here https://phpdelusions.net/pdo/common_mistakes